Unable to resolve module @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault
Unable to resolve module @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault
I am new to react native, I have a monorepo project using Yarn and lerna which I am trying to build for iOS but I am getting error Unable to resolve module @babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault. I have checked the Project structure runtime folder is not present in babel folder of node modules.
I have tried many solutions available on internet like
adding the babel and do Yarn install,
delete node modules and Yarn install,
verified babel.config.js file
